# How to fix "fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory #include <openssl/opensslv.h>"

Tags: openssl, cross-compiling

I'm trying to compile Android kernel on Ubuntu 22.04, and I got this:

```bash
/LineageOS/LinageOS/kernel/xiaomi/nitrogen/scripts/sign-file.c:23:30: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/opensslv.h>
```

However, many answers told me to install 'libssl-dev', which I did it as follows.

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libssl-dev is already the newest version (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

but it doesn't work for me, I got the same error. And I also tried `openssl`, It didn't work   either.

Is there any suggestions for me ?